# Whats the best way to use AWS elasticache with RDS MultiAZ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elasticache

I'm currently using RDS MultiAZ from Amazon Web Services on my project, and I was hoping to use ElastiCache to improve the speed of my queries. However I noticed that on ElastiCache I have to define which zone I'm interesting in using.

Just to check if I got it right: MultiAZ means that I have 2 database servers on 2 zones (I'm using South America region): on zone A I have a read and write server (Master) and on zone B I have a read server (Slave). If for any reason zone A goes down, zone B becomes the Master until Zone A returns.

Now how do use ElastiCache (I'm using Memcache) in this case? I can't create a cache cluster with a single endpoint to connect, and 2 nodes (one in each zone). I need to have 1 cache cluster for each zone, and 2 codes for my application so they'll connect to the correct zone?

Already asked that on AWS forums a month ago, but had no response.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon ElastiCache clusters are per-AZ and there is no Multi-AZ for ElastiCache as there is for RDS (you are right, that is master/slave replication). So you would need to design around that. This is very context dependent, but here are three ideas:

- Failure Recovery: monitor your cache cluster and, in the event of a failure, spin a new one in another AZ.
- Master/Slave: have a standby cache cluster and, in the event of a failure, reroute and scale to the slave.
- Multi master: have per-AZ cache clusters always up under a Elastic Load Balancer.

**EDIT**

This answer considers ElasticCache for Memcached. For Redis there is Multi-AZ (master/slave) support.

Comment: I liked the idea of associating a Elastic Load Balancer with 2 cache clusters, one in each zone. But how do I implement that using Amazon's Elasticache service? The only way I think that is possible is installing memcache in EC2 instances and hooking them to the load balancer. I want to use Amazon's service instead.

Comment: You coud use another load balancer (such as NGINX) with the two ElastiCache cache clusters as backend servers. Some memcached clients do loadbalancing and failover, in these cases you just need to add both servers to the list, no need to load balance server side.

Comment: Another option would be to use Redis instead of Memcached as the cache engine, that supports Multi-AZ.